# Ubuntu Server, Postfix, Localhost, Temporary Lookup Failure

Tags: server, email, postfix, localhost

I installed Ubuntu Server 18.04, installed Apache, MySQL, PhpMyAdmin, Postfix, Dovecot, Mailman, etc from the Ubuntu Server guide on Ubuntu Documentation website and I am getting this error when attempting to send an email thru Squirrelmail:

```
Message not sent. Server replied:
Requested action aborted: error in processing
451 4.3.0 <root@localhost>: Temporary lookup failure
```

Also:

```
dns@mycroft:/etc/postfix$ telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mycroft ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
helo mycroft
250 mycroft
mail from: dns@localhost
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to: root@localhost
451 4.3.0 <root@localhost>: Temporary lookup failure
```

Here is my /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mycroft
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = localhost, localhost.localdomain
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter =
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
default_transport = error
relay_transport = error
inet_protocols = ipv4
home_mailbox = Maildir/
relay_domains = localhost
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
mailman_destination_recipient_limit = 1
myorigin = localhost
```

I am only wanting to send mail locally on the host, so nothing outbound at this point, and I unable to send from one user to the other on the server.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

-Levi